# What happens if you break the Old Barbarian Statue?

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-of-clans-builder-base

As the title asks, what happens if you break (the original) Old Barbarian Statue in the builders base? I have looked online but there isn't much continuity in what it does. Some sources say you get 3 gems, others say 3-5 gems, I think it drops a random number of gems (like breaking any other decoration does), so does anyone have a definite answer for what breaking it gives? Sources/multiple video proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an obstacle, the same as any of the other large stones. This one has a unique look and produces the grass around it so it costs more to remove. But at the end of the day **you're only going to get 1 to maybe 5 gems** or so.

There is a movable version to purchase in the shop.

My experience removing it - 2 gems.

Other screen snippets from various videos:

[image]
[image]
[image]